# How do I call a childs class method from a parent abstract class

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Hi guys I'm pretty new in java and still learning OOP principles. Straight to the question. So I have one abstract class and two classes that inherit from it. It looks like this:

```
public abstract class A { ... }
public class B extends A { 
    ...
    void methodB() { ... }

public class C extends A {
    ...
    void methodC() { ... }
```

Now I do:

```
A a = null;
if (that)
    a = new B();
else
    a = new C();
```

And at **this** point I want to do either
    `a.methodB();`
or `a.methodC();` *(of course not both because I created one child)* **but I can't do neither.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can do it:

```
if (a instanceof B) ((B)a).methodB();
else if (a instanceof C) ((C)a).methodC();
```

But this is an anti-pattern and I recommend the definition of `methodA` as an `abstract` method in the `A` `abstract` `class`. `B` and `C` would implement it both and then you could easily call `a.methodA()` and the correct implementation of `methodA` will be called then.

Answer (score 2):

You are violating the OOPS concepts. because parent class don't need to know the child behavior. What you can do create a abstract method in class A. and then called the method A.something(). just override it something method in B and C class and give the same implementation what you may give in methodB and methodC.

```
public abstract class A { abstract something(); }

public  class B { overide something(){} }

public  class C { overide something(){} }

A a = null;
if (that)
  a = new B();
else
  a = new C();

if that is true then it equivalent to B.something() else C.something(). You can read more about method overriding/runtime polymorphism.
```

Comment: shouldn't B and C not be marked abstract?

Comment: yes, updated comment B and C don't need to be abstract . Thank you

Answer (score 2):

> How do I call a childs class method from a parent abstract class

This is not possible. Using the reference of the supertype, you can access only members of the supertype as per the [access control mechanism](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) directly. However, you can cast the reference to the subclass and to access the members of the subclass.

## How to check the type of instance?

Use [instanceof](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html) operator for it.

---

**Demo:**

```
abstract class SomeA {
    abstract void commonMethod();
}

class SomeB extends SomeA {
    void methodB() {
        System.out.println("methodB()");
    }

    @Override
    public void commonMethod() {
        System.out.println("SomeB's implementation of commonMethod()");
    }
}

class SomeC extends SomeA {
    void methodC() {
        System.out.println("methodC()");
    }

    @Override
    public void commonMethod() {
        System.out.println("SomeC's implementation of commonMethod()");
    }
}

public class Testing {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SomeB bb = new SomeB();
        bb.commonMethod();
        bb.methodB();

        SomeC cc = new SomeC();
        cc.commonMethod();
        cc.methodC();

        SomeA b = new SomeB();
        SomeA c = new SomeC();
        System.out.println(b instanceof SomeB);
        System.out.println(c instanceof SomeB);
        System.out.println(b instanceof SomeC);
        System.out.println(c instanceof SomeC);

        b.commonMethod();
        // b.methodB();//Error as b is a reference of super type
        ((SomeB) b).commonMethod();// Fine after casting the super type reference to SomeB

        c.commonMethod();
        // c.methodC();//Error as c is a reference of super type
        ((SomeC) c).commonMethod();// Fine after casting the super type reference to SomeC
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
SomeB's implementation of commonMethod()
methodB()
SomeC's implementation of commonMethod()
methodC()
true
false
false
true
SomeB's implementation of commonMethod()
SomeB's implementation of commonMethod()
SomeC's implementation of commonMethod()
SomeC's implementation of commonMethod()
```